# ns-2 error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."

Tags: linux, ns2

In ns-2 I get this error, even I re install mu ns-2.

```
ns: _o5136 unknown-flow 44 127 1061001022: 

    (_o5136 cmd line 1)
    invoked from within

"_o5136 cmd unknown-flow 44 127 1061001022"

    invoked from within

"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"

    invoked from within

"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {

set cls [$self info class]

global errorInfo

set savedInfo $errorInfo

error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."

    (procedure "_o5136" line 2)

    (SplitObject unknown line 2)

    invoked from within

"_o5136 unknown-flow 44 127 1061001022"
```

I am not able to understand from which procedure this error is generated.

Please any one can help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue after implementing ZRP protocol in ns2. The root cause of this issue is a spelling mistake: a syntax error in the modified code. The solution to this problem is to run `>sudo make -k in "./ns-2.3*"`. You will get the list of errors: just resolve each and you are done.